# Combine(merge) multiple dictionaries in list respectively

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list called `dlist`  that has a number of dictionaries with same keys ('Remark:').

```
dlist = [{'Remark:': 'S : RIH W/14" MAGNET (3TIMES) R I H W/2-1/2 R.CIR BASKET &    C'},
 {'Remark:': 'ORRING F/64 TO 64.6 P O H NO CONE, LAY DOWN F.TOOL @ RT.       R'},
 {'Remark:': 'RIH W/14" MAGNET & 8-1/2 DC TO 64 MT & CIR ON TOP OF FISH &   100'}]
```

I want to combine values of dictionaries respectively to have meaningful sentence (The order of the sentences is important for me). I used following code:

```
Combine_Dict2 = {item['Remark:'] for item in dlist if isinstance(item, dict) and 'Remark:' in item}
```

my output is:

```
Combine_Dict2 = {'ORRING F/64 TO 64.6 P O H NO CONE, LAY DOWN F.TOOL @ RT.       Ra, 'RIH W/14" MAGNET & 8-1/2 DC TO 64 MT & CIR ON TOP OF FISH &   100', 'S : RIH W/14" MAGNET (3TIMES) R I H W/2-1/2 R.CIR BASKET &    C'}
```

The order of the sentences is not observed. please help me.

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension instead of a set comprehension to maintain order:

Change:

```
Combine_Dict2 = {item['Remark:'] for item in dlist if isinstance(item, dict) and 'Remark:' in item}
```

To

```
Combine_Dict2 = [item['Remark:'] for item in dlist if isinstance(item, dict) and 'Remark:' in item]
```

Using `{}` makes it a set comprehension, `[]` is a list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `set-comprehension` syntax  with the brackets `{}` around your statement, which builds a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) (and not a `dict`) which is an unordered collection.

You need a `list-comprehension` to keep iteration order :

```
result = [item['Remark:'] for item in dlist 
                          if isinstance(item, dict) and 'Remark:' in item]


['S : RIH W/14" MAGNET (3TIMES) R I H W/2-1/2 R.CIR BASKET &    C', 
 'ORRING F/64 TO 64.6 P O H NO CONE, LAY DOWN F.TOOL @ RT.       R', 
 'RIH W/14" MAGNET & 8-1/2 DC TO 64 MT & CIR ON TOP OF FISH &   100']
```

Comment: Dear Barmar,,, Kinds of Regard